# Qemu hanging in main system call

Tags: operating-system, qemu, osdev, pintos

I was working on the [Pintos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pintos) project . And while I was implementing a priority donation mechanism for the proper priority scheduling , QEMU emulator just hung up (I have attached an image and the dump of the pintos is as below ) . I tried debugging and inserting printf statements , but during debugging qemu via a remote host , it again hung up as soon as it entered main . Can anybody tell me how do I troubleshoot all this . Otherwise I will have to reinstall the entire code and qemu and everything in between .

The dump from pintos:

```
sankalps@ubuntu:~/projects/os_projects/pintos/src$ pintos --gdb -- run alarm-zero
qemu -hda /tmp/IbpgyXzQhW.dsk -m 4 -net none -serial stdio -s -S
open /dev/kvm: No such file or directory
Could not initialize KVM, will disable KVM support
PiLo hda1
Loading.........
Kernel command line: run alarm-zero
made it till here
```

[image: Pintos emulated on QEMU]Pintos emulated on QEMU

Answer (score 4):

I think either you don't have the right kernel version or your hardware doesn't support virtualization,may be both

do `lsmod | grep kvm`
see if the module kvm and kvm_intel are loaded
if not then use `modprobe kvm kvm_intel` to load the modules.
 If these modules cant be loaded then probably your machine cant support KVM you can find this by `grep --color vmx /proc/cpuinfo`if the you output contains vmx or svx then hardware virtualization is supported and you need the right kernel version.Linux started to give KVM support from the version 2.6.36.4  .By compiling the new kernel I guess you wont face this problem.If the problem is that your machine is capable of virtualization but kernel's not supporting.Heres a [link](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/csl862-virt/lec/hw3.html) on how to set up the machine.See the lab and tools link.Check out the courses offered list and search for labs and tools in them you will find lot of stuff on how to set up QEMU , BOCHS ,start a VM etc.
Also you can try using bochs,I assume you are doing pintos as a part of your OS course.So can change the emulator to be used in the command line by setting `--EMULATOR=bochs`(something like that)
Although your VM will be a little slower you wont face a problem of KVM support not available.

Cheers :)